# How to create input mask in text field of flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, textfield, input-mask

I am working on a project in flutter I want to mask the input so that the user won't input the information in wrong format, I tired to google is as well bit couldn't find anything helpful

Please guide me how to make the mask example given in figure

[image]

Comment: Do you need mask-like password input or format the input value?

Comment: Format the input value for example
12345-1234567-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For input format you should use **TextFormField** with **TextInputFormatter**. Have you tried that?

A nice article about this can be found [here](https://medium.com/@rubensdemelo/flutter-formatting-textfield-with-textinputformatter-6caba78668e5). It also contains links to flutter API for more in-depth configurations.

Comment: This helped a lot but not completely answer my question, it adds - after a constant number of numbers I want input like 12345-1234567-1

Comment: Give it a try by using WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp("([0-9]+(-[0-9]+)+)"). It should result in the right format.